# How to pass Mongoose return variable in NodeJS Express router res.render?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I had set a basic Express NodeJS server.

I want to save the value of the setting returned from mongoose.find() to res.render as a variable, but every time it's throwing me an error that `Cannot read property of undefined`.

Here is my routes.js file.

```
var Setting = require('../../models/setting');

module.exports = function(app, passport) {
 app.get('/admin', function(req, res) {
    Setting.find(function(err, setting) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(500, err);
        }
        console.log(setting);
        res.render('admin/customize/settings', {
            title: 'Change Setting | eduBird',
            user: req.user,
            setting: res.setting
                // setting: res.settings
        });
    });

});
```

This is my setting model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var settingSchemma = mongoose.Schema({
 logo: {
    logo16: String,
    logo32: String,
    logo96: String,
    logo128: String,
    logo128white: String
 }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Setting', settingSchemma);
```

Here is the error in the browser, I am using pug view.

`name='logo32' value=setting.logo.logo32) Cannot read property 'logo' of undefined`

Here is my the log in my terminal, notice that `console.log(setting)` is executing the settings right, since I have just one document for logo.

```
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www server`
  Server running on port3000
  [ { _id: 58ac45xxxx3xxxxf3,
   __v: 0,
  logo:
 { logo128white: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/xxxxx/image/uplo
   ad/xxxxx/128x128-white_aqya8e.png',
   logo128: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/xxxxx/image/upload/v1
   xxxxxxx/128x128_jn9dzz.png',
   logo96: '',
   logo32: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/xxxx/image/upload/v14
    xxxxx/32x32_wtk3gk.png',
   logo16: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/pinterested222/image/upload/v14
     xxxx/16x16_o4gzhd.png' } } ]
  GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 6.947 ms - -
```

**Here is a snapshot**:
[Snapshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhxWn.png)

**UPDATE**

Here is the snippet of my .pug file, I am rendering, all indentations are right.

```
           form.logoForm.z-depth-3.col.s12(method='post' action='/settings/logo')
                .row
                    .col.s12.m8.offset-m2
                        h4.center Change Logo Settings
                        p.center Add URL for valid Logos.
                        .divider
                    .input-field.col.s12
                        input.validate#logo16(placeholder="URL for 16x16 .png log" name='logo16' value=setting.logo.logo16)
                        label.active(for='logo16') 16x16 Logo
                    .input-field.col.s12
                        input.validate#logo32(placeholder="URL for 32x32 .png log" name='logo32' value=setting.logo.logo32)
                        label.active(for='logo32') 32x32 Logo
                    .input-field.col.s12
                        input.validate#logo128(placeholder="URL for 128x128 .png log" name='logo128' value=setting.logo.logo128)
                        label.active(for='logo128') 128x128 Logo
                    .input-field.col.s12
                        input.validate#logo128white(placeholder="URL for 128x128 white .png log" name='logo128white' value=setting.logo.logo128)
                        label.active(for='logo128white') 128x128 Logo White(for dark bg)
                .row
                    .col.s12.m4.offset-m4.l4.offset-l4
                        button.center.logoSubmit.btn.btn-large.indigo.darken-4.white-text.waves-effect.waves-light.disabled Save #[i.fa.fa-chevron-circle-right.right]
                        button.center.btn.btn-large.indigo.darken-4.white-text.waves-effect.waves-light Save #[i.fa.fa-chevron-circle-right.right]
                    .col.s12.m6.offset-m3
                        p.center(style='margin-top: .3em; padding: .2em') *You can only save the settings if any of the form fields are different/updated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, the assignment `setting: res.setting` is the one causing the issue. Also, **[`find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)** returns an array of docs, not a single document. You may want to use **[`findOne()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)** for that:

```
var Setting = require('../../models/setting');

module.exports = function(app, passport) {
    app.get('/admin', function(req, res) {
        Setting.findOne({}).exec(function(err, setting) {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(500, err);
            }
            console.log(setting);
            res.render('admin/customize/settings', {
                title: 'Change Setting | eduBird',
                user: req.user,
                setting: setting                    
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @chridam you saved my day. I tried using `setting:setting` several times but didn't notice and knew that `Setting.find()` would return an error instead.
`Setting.findOne()` works great. :)